# How can I cache all pages I visit with Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser-cache

Q: How can I cache all pages I visit in a given session with Firefox?

I frequently go to study with my laptop at a library where I don't have internet access (no login). I usually research somethings in the internet the day before and I wanted to make Firefox cache all data from the webpages so that when I'm at the library I can go back to something I read on the internet.

I have these config settings:

```
browser.cache.check_doc_frequency;3  
browser.cache.disk.capacity;500000  
browser.cache.disk.enable;true  
browser.cache.disk_cache_ssl;true  
browser.cache.frecency_experiment;4  
browser.cache.memory.enable;true (should I set this to false?)  
browser.cache.offline.capacity;512000  
browser.cache.offline.enable;true  
browser.cache.disk_cache_ssl;true
```

Even clearing all my cache before, some elements, like images, for some reason are sometimes not stored in the cache, even though they display fine on the tab when the page loads. But if I reload the page, they are stored.

There's an Addon called [Session Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/session-manager/) that allows me to save the current session. But it would be best if I could save the whole history, because sometimes I forget to store some page I read that turns out to be important. That's why I want to cache everything (disk space is not a problem), so that in ["offline mode"](http://www.howtogeek.com/263854/how-to-enable-offline-browsing-in-firefox/) I can go back to them in Firefox.

There are related questions, but they don't provide my solution:
[Auto save all visited pages in Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/385658/auto-save-all-visited-pages-in-firefox)
[Browse local copies of websites when possible (Firefox with slow internet connection)](https://superuser.com/questions/314138/browse-local-copies-of-websites-when-possible-firefox-with-slow-internet-connec)
[Browsing cached pages with no internet connection](https://superuser.com/questions/861749/browsing-cached-pages-with-no-internet-connection)

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't the linked questions answer your question?

Comment: Try [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org), it's also a good archive and research tool.

Comment: @Arjan because they don't reach a solution of caching everything, the solutions are different Addons (that may no longer be supported) etc.

Comment: It is not capturing everything, so it may not be what you are looking for, but you could also use a note taking application, e.g., Evernote or onenote. It is very easy to safe webpages in such programs, and you get to search in your notes to boot.

Comment: Would installing a proxy server (like Squid) on your pc be an option for you? See [this](http://superuser.com/questions/463893/caching-in-modern-browsers-sucks-why-and-how-to-fix) answer.

Comment: @agtoever thanks for the suggestion, but, like the OP from that thread, I think it's overkill to use Squid just for that (besides, it might not work, because some headers prohibit that cacheing to a proxy - even though this might be a rare problem for me). It seems difficult and would take me a long time to learn it

Comment: @sander123 I think you're right, like Atzmon said with Zotero. From the options I saw, I think I prefer Scrapbook X to Zotero or Evernote. My only problem is that quite often I forget to bookmark/save something important and I have to go back to the page where I saw it. But with no internet it's not possible. So if I could save my whole browsing history for that session, that would be best

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might not be able to store (cache) every page you visited automatically. But you can save any webpage completely (with CSS, images, etc.) into a single HTML file that can be opened in any browser. This is similar to the [MHTML feature in chromium browsers](https://www.tagspaces.org/blog/mhtml-saving-chrome/) (Google Chrome, Opera, etc).

Addons
01: [SingleFile | Save a page as a single HTML file](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/single-file/) by [gildas](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/user/14142901/)
02: [Save Page WE](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/save-page-we/) by [DW-dev](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/user/1236621/)

Sample Screenshot of this webpage using SingleFile addon

[image: Screenshot]

**Update...**

There is a feature in [SingleFile](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/single-file/) Firefox add-on that will let you automatically save every page you visit.

[image: Screenshot of SingleFile Autosave feature]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! The problem is that I was searching for a way to do this automatically, saving the session so that I could go back to each site (without needing to manually saving everything). Nowadays I don't go to this library anymore, I mostly study at home, but maybe the question can be useful for someone else

Comment: That's my hope as well. :)

Comment: @flen there is now an auto-save add-on, have you tried it?

Comment: This question is 3 years old and isn't relevant to me anymore, so I won't try the solution, but I'm accepting it as answer because it seems to solve the problem